# Oracle module for PHP in Linux

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

Is there any method for direct access to remotely hosted Oracle Database without installing oracle in my computer.

I already had the host name, database name, username and password of the remotely hosted Oracle database. I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5 (Tikanga) and no Oracle yet install.

Your help would be precious.
Thank you in advance

Comment: does this help? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install the **oci8** PHP extension, see [**here**](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/tutoriels/typo3/articles/oracle-database/oracle-support-for-php.html#c719) for a tutorial.